# Compiling Code - error CS1056 '`'

Tags: codedom

I am trying to compile a code using my own compiler (CodeDOM), but on codes like this:

```
390.   sealed class FunctorComparer`1 {
421.   public System.Array+FunctorComparer`1[T] () {}
448.   abstract public interface IEnumerator`1 {
... (1676 matches) ...
```

i am getting this error:

```
c:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\0z4zag32.0.cs(390,29) : error CS1056: Unexpected character '`'
```

what am I missing?

---

```
[EDIT (1, "16:25", "4 May")]
the code i m trying to compile is not written by me. I don't know what that
character stands for, learning it. But i found that on this site
http://submain.com/ghostdoc/samples/PowerCollections/HTML/html/75549028.htm
it is being used, and it is strange the CodeDOM doesnt parse it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of any member (field, property, method, class) can not contain the character

```
'`'
```

If you are reading details from

```
System.Reflection
```

It will add this character, i m not sure it s need, may be because it is overidding a virtual member x times. like

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult] //1 time
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`6[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult] //6 times
```

Just taking the first part of the declaration is complete, and contains all the informations the computer needs to do the work.

```
from
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]

to
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
```

Answer (score 0):

The backticks should be removed from the code.  This is what the error code is hinting at.

They were likely added due to an overzealous escaping on the part of the system you're getting this code sample from.

Comment: are we sure that removing that character will work? how this should be written: 
`System.Threading.Tasks.Task\`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]`

Comment: I'm going to stick to that sentiment, as I've quickly glanced at the documentation and didn't see the backtick as a valid character.  Further, the error code is explicitly telling you that it doesn't expect the backtick character in those positions.

Comment: okay, because the code is not written by me, like this variable is read from `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.PropertyType`